# deploying codeigniter 3.0.1 app on openshift

Tags: php, codeigniter, openshift

I have a fine running app on localhost using WAMP server but my app is not running correctly on live server, 404 page appears with "The page you requested was not found." ( http://testcode-researcherloby.rhcloud.com/ ) 
i can't seem to get what goes wrong in configuration, also i tested simpe CI app with absolutely nothing on it and it was running fine.
This is the path setting in my config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

This is database.php file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => '', //for security purpose i'm removing username
'password' => '', //and password but i have checked them, they are right
'database' => 'testcode',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

What changes i need to do ? Tell me if any other file is required i'll post it. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: So what controller is this URL mapped to? The error you are getting is CI-styled, so it doesn't seem like a server misconfiguration, however, it looks like it might be some routing issue, not clear mapping to a controller for that URL for instance.

Comment: i have set default router `$route['default_controller'] = 'user_authentication';`

Comment: And is this an existing controller in your system? Is there any index method in the controller? It might be useful to try to read a bit on the request life-cycle, how requests are handled in CI, it's an interesting read in fact: [app-flow](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html)

Comment: @Thanos yes it has index.php for now i haven't removed the index thingy yet. But even if we feed anyother url it gives the same page. I remember i had that similar error when i was trying to remove index from url

Comment: is there something wrong with router ? I have read some other info people were having issue with their constructor in their class but i have everything fine there, still can't figure out what's the cause of the problem

Comment: In codeigniter 3 or higher version The view name must start with capital latter for example index page name must be Index.php

Comment: @Yaseen can you link me to the documentation where it's said ?

Comment: i don't know this is my own experience with codeigniter  try this if isn't work let know.

Comment: @Yaseen no effect, same error

Comment: go to your controller function and echo some text there and let me know. is your function working.

Comment: @Yaseen same page, not printing anything seems like my path is wrong for the config file.

Comment: know try index.php/contorller-name/function_name if it's work let me know if not go to your codeigniter index.php and echo some thing and exit if it's if it's not work let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111220/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-yaseen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check files name inside Model directory and inside Controller directory, the first name should be capital.